# How to rename files that contain spaces with a bat script?

Tags: batch-file

Consider the following file:

```
DOC 00001.txt
```

I need to rename it to

```
DOC 00001_XXX_YYY - DOC 00001
```

I'm trying this using a `.bat` file with the following command:

```
rename "DOC 00001.txt" "DOC 00001_XXX_YYY - DOC 00001"
```

But this doesn't work. So I tried to it (just for debugging sake) with replacing the space in the file with an underscore:

```
rename "DOC_00001.txt" "DOC 00001_XXX_YYY - DOC 00001"
```

This still didn't work. What Does work is:

```
rename "DOC_00001.txt" "DOC_00001_XXX_YYY_-_DOC_00001"
```

So the problem is in the spaces. But I cannot find what `rename` command will work with spaces. Can anybody help me?

Comment: what is not working, do you have an error ? if so what is it ?

Comment: The ren commands in all three lower code blocks will work fine, in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

What you have should work:

```
C:\Users\marc>echo > "DOC 00001.txt"

C:\Users\marc>ren "DOC 00001.txt" "DOC 00001_XXX_YYY - DOC 00001"

C:\Users\mbb190>dir DOC*
 Volume in drive C is Windows7_OS
 Volume Serial Number is 0E31-0E35

 Directory of C:\Users\marc

20/09/2013  08:28 AM                13 DOC 00001_XXX_YYY - DOC 00001
```

If it's not renaming, then check if you've got a filename conflict, or are otherwise lacking permissions somehow.

Comment: Why are you assuming file doesn't exist? Why are you OVERWRITING existing file?

Comment: @ls_dev  The command is creating a file (with an error message inside it) and then renaming the file.  No overwriting going on there.

Comment: @LS_dev: I hope you realize that the sample above is from MY machine, where I was demonstrating that the rename command SHOULD work?

Comment: @foxidrive and @marcb: @prono wants to rename existing files, of course. In my opinion, this example may be dangerous because if @prono just types what is suggested, he will overwrite existing "DOC 00001.txt" with (not an error) `ECHO is on` message - as you both  well know!

Comment: @ls_dev Yes: if prono is using the actual filename and types in the commands, in the same folder, then it will destroy the contents of that file.  I see what you mean.  prono will be aware now, and may have known already.